# join values of 2 tables and display data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables, cart and product. User can choose product from product table and then its details are added to cart table. i wanted a listing that combines the values of these two tables and gives a result

prodsize

```
id   catid   catname  productid   prodsize     cost    prodname
1     2      CN1        13          small      130     P1
2     2      CN1        13          large      200     P1
3     2      CN1        14          small      50      P2
4     2      CN1        14          medium     90      P2
5     2      CN1        14          large      110     P2
6     2      CN1        12          small      70      P3
7     2      CN1        12          medium     110     P3
8     2      CN1        13          medium     200     P1
```

cart

```
id   catid  catname  userid  productid   prodname  prodsize   prodcost  quantity    status 
1     2        CN1      1       13          P1       small      130       2       add_to_cart 
1     2        CN1      1       13          P1       large      200       2       order_placed
```

when i run the following query combined value from both the table  but here i want that only those products quantity should get displayed whose status is add_to_cart, if the status is order_placed then the quantity should be 0, can anyone plz tell how can i modify the below code to get desired result

```
$sql= "SELECT p.catid, p.catname, p.productid, p.prodimg, GROUP_CONCAT(p.prodsize ORDER BY p.id ASC) as size, GROUP_CONCAT(p.cost ORDER BY p.id ASC) as cost, p.prodname,
   GROUP_CONCAT(c.prodsize,'-',c.quantity) as cart_details, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(c.userid)) as user_id
   FROM productsize p
   LEFT JOIN cart c ON(c.productid = p.productid AND c.userid = '$userid' AND p.prodsize = c.prodsize)
   WHERE p.catid ='$catid' 
   GROUP BY p.productid
   ORDER BY user_id DESC, p.productid ASC";
```

Comment: Add a `where` clause to your query.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff i have tried that but its not workin

Comment: Reading a little closer I think you need a case expression to handle some conditional logic ib your output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about your two conditions ("ordered" items shouldn't get displayed, and should have quantity 0).  If they have a quantity 0, they need to be displayed, right?  Anyhow, here's my fix considering you may want to do the latter (get "ordered" items in your query result with a quantity of 0)

1. You need to group by `productid` AND `status`
2. You need a quantity as an aggregate SUM that takes the status into account

Cleaned up some other things too (e.g. quoted indexes, which will harm performance):

```
$sql = "SELECT p.catid, p.catname, p.productid, p.prodimg, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(p.prodsize ORDER BY p.id ASC) as size, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(p.cost ORDER BY p.id ASC) as cost, p.prodname,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.prodsize,'-',c.quantity) as cart_details, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(c.userid)) as user_id,
            SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 'add_to_cart' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS quantity
        FROM productsize p
        LEFT JOIN cart c ON(c.productid = p.productid 
            AND p.prodsize = c.prodsize)
            AND c.userid = {$userid}
        WHERE p.catid = {$catid}
        GROUP BY p.productid, c.status
        ORDER BY p.productid ASC";
```

Comment: The filter on userid can't happen in the where clause without defeating the left join.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the where clause.  Try adding

```
AND status = 'add_to_cart'
```

just after the existing where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Change `c.quantity` to:

```
case c.status
    when 'add_to_cart' then c.quantity
    else 0
end
```

Since you used a left join, the zero result will also apply when that product didn't appear in the user's cart.

And note that the sort on `userid` may be effectively ordering the cart and non-cart products but that is the wrong way to express that intention. It's also best to aggregate the non-group columns everywhere.